# Go test Difference between maps

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to run some tests on json objects. Currently I have a function to compare the json string and output an error message if they don't match:

```
func assertJsonEqual(expected, actual string) bool {
    actualStruct := make(map[string]interface{})
    expectedStruct := make(map[string]interface{})

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(expected), &expectedStruct)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(actual), &actualStruct)

    if !reflect.DeepEqual(expectedStruct, actualStruct) {
        log.Errorf("Expected: %#v\n but got %#v", expectedStruct, actualStruct)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

The problem is this makes it really hard to see exactly which key is missing or extra in the actual tool. I'm thinking about building a simple diff of the map keys, but am wondering if there is an existing library that already does this?

Answer (score 2):

There's not an existing function, it's like 5 lines of code.

```
diff := &[]string{} // initialize some storage for the diff

for _, k := range map1 { // range over one of the maps
    if _, ok := map2[k]; !ok { // check if the key from the first map exists in the second
        diff = append(diff, k)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that since there can be nested differences. I'll go ahead and try to make my own then.

Comment: @JoshWilson or you could just define a struct and then define a method for that struct that does a deep equals... Writing generic code for no reason is stupid and usually leads to poor quality. Beyond that since the actual json is apparently missing keys it would just fail at the point of unmarshalling.